# Why isn't boot-repair in the official Ubuntu repositories?

Tags: boot-repair, software-sources

Why is this the case? Should I add a PPA to install it/get updates? I thought it was licensed under the GPL.

Answer (score 4):

According to [a Launchpad bug page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/boot-repair/+bug/806291), it needs a sponsor to upload it to the Ubuntu and Debian repositories. I read down the thread a bit and, while its rather old, it seems the developer still has no sponsor.

Comment: Why does he need sponsor in order to upload it there ?

Comment: @RS because things cost money /:

Comment: @cat very "precise and userful" answer

Comment: @RS It can't get much more detailed than that. Things do cost money, and that includes maintaining a spot in an official repo.